# PHP FPM Working, but ignoring version from SetHandler

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm

Our server is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-135-generic x86_64).

We followed the directions from https://tecadmin.net/install-multiple-php-version-apache-ubuntu/ a while back and got PHP 5.6 and 7.2 running back when 7.2 was new, and have upgraded and added 7.3 and 7.4 with no problems until this morning.  Yesterday it worked fine but today it is not. We package update early yesterday but it didn't require a reboot and don't believe it rebooted overnight on its own as `uptime` says we're close to 15 days.

So today we set about going through the process again and have done this, restarting apache2 after every step:

Tried:

```
a2enmod actions fcgid alias proxy_fcgi
```

and got:

```
ERROR: Module fcgid does not exist!
```

Did `apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid` and that **worked** and added the package.

Did `a2enmod actions fcgid alias proxy_fcgi` and it said everything **already enabled**.

Checked conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Tried `phpinfo()` page and got PHP 7.4.15 instead of expected 5.6.40. We did the same with a 7.3 and got the same 7.4 on `phpinfo()` using SetHandler of php7.3 as well.

Then tried `systemctl status php5.6-fpm` and `php7.4-fpm` and got both `active (running)`.

My `/etc/apache2/conf/php5.6-fpm.conf` file is here for starters, and the one for `php7.4-fpm.conf` is the same except for `mod_php5/7` and the `SetHandler` version:

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Is there an error here or somewhere else I should look?

FWIW, we have another server with a similar setup and it is having the same issue, but we only need the 5.6 legacy application on that server at this time so we just disabled 7.4 by removing the pointer file in  `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.4-fpm.conf` and restarting `apache2`.  However, this server needs multiple versions.

Comment: Can confirm, across 6 instances of Ubuntu 20.04 as of this week only the latest PHP-FPM is used. `SetHandler` directives to set a VHOST to a specific version is completely ignored. I currently have to `a2disconf php8.0-fpm` and restart Apache to prevent PHP 8.0 being used at all.

Comment: Interestingly this problem only seems to impact Ubuntu, and likely its derivatives too. Our company's dozen or so Debian 10 instances using the same Apache and PHP-FPM configurations work completely as expected, as do my half dozen personal Debian 10 instances. I've double checked the same Apache modules are enabled, literally identical.

Comment: Interesting, I guess that makes it a Ubuntu issue over a PHP issue. I know our 5.6 instance has a "+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" after the version. I just wish I knew where to go digging with that but seems we're at the mercy of the Ubuntu updates for now.

Comment: I was going to ask if many of you use the (excellent) Sury repository, and did look at its issue board for reports of this fault. To me it appears that the issue is with Apache not routing to the correct PHP-FPM as configured rather than PHP (or PHP-FPM). As far as I know Sury distribute the same packages to both Debian and Apache so I would currently be inclined to think Sury's packages are not the problem. (Though someone more expert on the repository is very welcome to correct me on this.)

Comment: I've filed this with Ubuntu officially here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/695605

Comment: Seems I can't comment because of lack of reputation. I encountered the same issue recently and have detailed my struggles and solutions here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1108437/why-are-my-2-sites-on-the-same-server-randomly-switching-php-versions-with-ph
I was able to workaround the issue in 2 ways: switch away from using sockets, or use htaccess files for each site instead of apache configs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

for:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
   <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Could you explain your proposition a little bit?  It is better to know why such a change is necessary than to blindly copy and paste a piece of code.

Comment: That line just check that the file exists.

Not sure why, but it works. It's the way the default /etc/apache2/conf/php5.6-fpm.conf file configure the SetHandler.

Comment: It is the way the default php5.6-fpm.conf file configures the SetHandler, but we are having this problem with php5.6 as well. That is in my original php5.6-fpm.conf file posted in the original question, so unfortunately this solution does not work with our setup, and I'm still not sure what is different.

Comment: @Alfredo, I changed it in the sites-available conf file for the individual site as that had the same line in our setup, and that did the trick for us. I'm curious to see what the Ubuntu team says!

Comment: Can confirm that wrapping `SetHandler` with `<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">` resolves this. Outrageous! But thank you kindly @Alfredo.

Answer (score 3):

Since I update my OS (ubuntu 20.04 LTS) on 15 feb 2021, I started to have this PROBLEM. Now php 8.0 is used for all my sites, instead of SetHandler configs

Answer (score 0):

> Run updates.  I had the same problem, now realized it started after
> the last set of php updates. Just ran the latest updates again and now
> it works again.

Okay, spoke to soon, the updates didn't fix it.

Here's what did work for me:

**EDIT: This was put in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.local.conf. Here's the entire file:**

```
<VirtualHost site1.local:80>
    <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
        <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
            # Enable http authorization headers
            <IfModule setenvif_module>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
            </IfModule>

            <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
                <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
                    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
                </If>
            </FilesMatch>
            <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
                # Deny access to raw php sources by default
                # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
                # only in specific virtual host or directory
                Require all denied
            </FilesMatch>
            # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
            <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
                Require all denied
            </FilesMatch>
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site1/docroot"
    ServerName site1.local
    <Directory "/var/www/site1/docroot">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule> 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Essentially this is the code copied from the /etc/conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf file.  As I'm not an expert on Apache I can't explain why it worked when the simpler statement didn't.  But I've edited three different vhosts and they are now getting the correct version of PHP.

Comment: I have the same problem. There's no more updates

Comment: This is what I had in my php5.6-fpm.conf except wrapped around an `<IfModule !mod_php5.c>` so I removed that and restarted php5.6-fpm and apache2 but still don't have any change.  For kicks, I removed the `<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>` as well and that didn't seem to do it for me.  Thanks for the update and code sample and glad it worked for you.  Is your conf file still just like `<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
 </FilesMatch>`

Comment: I replaced the <FilesMatch \.php$>  SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"  </FilesMatch> with the above code.

Comment: so, the trick is this: ```         <FilesMatch \".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$\"> # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
          <If \"-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\">
            SetHandler \"proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost\"
          </If>
        </FilesMatch>```

Comment: Thanks @joekrukosky ... turns out it was the `<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">` line that helps it, which you have here. We had to have it in the phpX.X-fpm.conf files as well as in the individual site.conf file in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the exact same on my Ubuntu WSL setup. However the following article was helpfull for a co-worker of mine so it might help you out aswell.

Avoid using *ProxyPassMatch*

```
# don't
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/
</IfModule>
```

Since *ProxyPassMatch* takes precedence over *FilesMatch* which u use for *SetHandler*

source:
https://ma.ttias.be/apache-2-4-proxypass-for-php-taking-precedence-over-filesfilesmatch-in-htaccess/

Comment: he is not using ProxyPassMatch

Comment: Thanks for the idea but couldn't find ProxyPassMatch anywhere in my config files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, I've experienced exactly same problem - only one version of PHP was showing up, the latest one. I tried to setup three PHP versions to run with the same Apache simultaneously.

It looked to me as if SetHandler line for all three configs was set to the same value of last loaded config file.
Config files was listed in following order in directory:

- */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5.6-fpm.conf*
- */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.4-fpm.conf*
- */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php8.1-fpm.conf*

Apache logs showed, every virtualhost I've created, which was supposed to run different version of PHP, was trying to connect to the same unix socket of php8.1.

Alfredos answer didn't solve the problem on its own for me.

**Solution** which worked for me was switching from using unix sockets to TCP sockets, as form of communication between apache2 and php-pfm.
To do that, I've modified those three files to set ip and listening port of php-pfm.

in file:
*/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9056
```

in file:
*/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9074
```

in file:
*/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9081
```

To reflect above changes in Apache, I've modified files: */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php*-fpm.conf* and */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/php*.mydomain.conf* so Apache can connect to proper ip/port. Config files incorporates Alfredos answer.

file */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5.6-fpm.conf* looks like this:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9056"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

file */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.4-fpm.conf* looks like this:

```
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9074"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

file */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php8.1-fpm.conf* looks like this:

```
<IfModule !mod_php8.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9081"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

My virtual hosts files looks like this:

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/php56.mydomain.com.conf* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName php56.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.php56.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php56
    <Directory /var/www/php56>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9056"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php56.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php56.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/php74.mydomain.com.conf* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName php74.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.php74.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php74
    <Directory /var/www/php74>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9074"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php74.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php74.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/php81.mydomain.com.conf* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName php81.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.php81.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php81
    <Directory /var/www/php81>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9081"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php81.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php81.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For reference:

```
#apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-10-14T16:24:43
```

I hope it helps and spare You some time.

**EDIT:**
To answer your question, is there an error in your config. Line with SetHandler may be a problem if you use TCP sockets, because port is not specified and that could cause Apache trying to connect to same PHP version.

Where else to look for:
Check if you have proper SetHandler lines in those files as well: */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/php*.mydomain.conf*

Check if SetHandler lines from above files match "listen" lines from following files:
*/etc/php/*/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192967)